# R, importing as matrix data, calculate sums of rows but exclude headers

Tags: r, matrix, header

I'm a student and working on a project and I fail to do a basic thing in R and its very frustrating.

```
data <- read.xlsx("dataset.xlsx",1, header=1)
#Creating a matrix with headers.
matrix <- as.matrix(data, row.names=1, col.names=1)

Sum <- rowSums(matrix, na.rm = FALSE, dims = 1)
```

The data looks something like this:

```
    Point1  Point2   Point3
SP1  0      1        1
SP1  0      1        0
SP1  1      1        0
SP1  1      1        1
SP1  0      1        0
```

This data is located and imported in R using the xlsx package. After that I want to calculate the row sums and import it in the matrix to create something like this:

```
    Point1  Point2   Point3  Sums
SP1  0      1        1       2
SP1  0      1        0       1
SP1  1      1        0       2
SP1  1      1        1       3
SP1  0      1        0       1
```

However, I can't get this to work. The code I used keeps returning non-numeric value. Obviously it probably tries to calculate with the first row and column, which are headers. For future purposes, Id like R to exclude the first row and column always and treat them as headers and treat the 0 and 1s as numeric.

Could you guys help me out here?

Cheers Jasper

Comment: Welcome to SO. With R it's helpful if you can provide a [minimal reproducible example] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), in your case this would mean providing a minimal data set. You can assign column names with [`colnames`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/colnames.html)

Comment: By the way, rowSums will not take into account the headers...make sure you convert your matrix as numeric, seems like you have characters in your matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your matrix contains characters and you try to sum them. So you first need to convert the submatrix you want to sum to `numeric` (it is better to use `class` here rather than `as.numeric` since it keeps the object type).
To add a new column to a matrix, you can use `cbind`. Then you can update the colnames.

Here is a one-liner:

```
`colnames<-`(cbind(matrix, rowSums(`class<-`(matrix[,-1], 'numeric'))),
             c(colnames(matrix), 'Sums'))

#           col1 col2 col3 Sums
#[1,] "Sp1" "1"  "0"  "0"  "1" 
#[2,] "Sp2" "1"  "0"  "0"  "1" 
#[3,] "Sp3" "1"  "1"  "0"  "2" 
#[4,] "Sp4" "0"  "1"  "1"  "2"
```

**Data**

```
matrix = structure(c('Sp1', 'Sp2', 'Sp3', 'Sp4', 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 1), .Dim = c(4L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("", "col1", "col2", "col3")))
```

Comment: This is somewhat useful, but the imported matrix already contains the headers and is more something like, so how do I make R get the headers from the file?: 

matrix = structure(c('Sp1', 'Sp2', 'Sp3', 'Sp4', 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1), .Dim = c(4L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("", "col1", "col2", "col3")))

Comment: @Jasperovic I don't know about `read.xlsx` but with `read.table` you can specify that the row.names are in the first column with `row.names=1` so maybe you can do that with `read.xlsx`?

Comment: Thanks a lot, it seems to work. However, one last question and I'll be off your back. How do I permanently add the row sums to my matrix? It prints the right matrix now, but when I recall matrix later its gone. Sorry for my ultra rookie-ness

Comment: Store my code in a new matrix `newMatrix = `colnames<-`(cbind...)` or in the matrix variable `matrix = `colnames<-`(cbind...)`. Modifying by reference is clearly not into R paradigm.

Comment: Actually, it is in two lines :-)

Comment: ;) I would have shorten the name of the matrix with `m` !